# Searching for specific values in a string SQL

Tags: sql, string, search

I need to search a string for a specific value that could appear anywhere within it, including at the beginning. It has to be an exact match on its own.

```
select * from LeadTimeNodes where ParentCombination like '%293 %'
```

So I need to find 293 as its own entity within the ParentCombination field.

Some examples of strings in the field:

```
'3293 >>> 671' should not find anything as 293 is part of a bigger number 3293

'293' should find it as it is on its own

'479 >>> 12930' should not find anything as 293 is part of 12930

'6000 >>> 293' should find it

'293 >>> 1600' should find it
```

If I use my sample code above, it incorporates the empty space into the search and works for numbers after, but if I put a space before it '% 293 %' then it won't find the strings that start with 293

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You need to use regexp for this purpose. ¿What's your database? Other solution less elegant is a combination of `likes` and `ors`: `ParentCombination like '293 %' OR ParentCombination like '% 293 %' OR ParentCombination like '% 293'`

Comment: What's the database? Maybe it can be done with regex if the engine supports them.

Comment: Apologies, I should've said, it's an SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

I went with James' Like & Or combination solution. May not have been the most eloquent but it did the trick.
Thanks

Comment: Please don't post an answer for an update to your question, rather mark the correct answer or update your question to include the steps you took if you cant mark a accepted answer yet.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle:

```
select REGEXP_Replace('3293 >>> 671', '(.*) >>> (.*)', '\1') as first_param,
REGEXP_Replace('3293 >>> 671', '(.*) >>> (.*)', '\2') as second_param
from dual;
```

This gives you output as two separate values. Then you can wrap it up in another select with exact string match.

Comment: Why that instead of `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE`?

Comment: because you will be adding multiple OR conditions with regexp_like, meaning using regex matching three times.